# How can a golang error reporting function get compilation information

Tags: go

How can a function establish the following details from the runtime so that it can craft appropriate error reporting as part of a error library to be used using in many products (we are changing over to golang):

- Compilation date and time of the executable
- Compilation machine used to create the executable

I would like to be able to retrieve both of these to augment the various file revision numbers that I can report along with some stack trace information

Useful related but off-topic information:
 - You can get stack traces out of the runtime as illustrated here http://technosophos.com/2014/03/19/generating-stack-traces-in-go.html
 - The reflect package http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/ can be used to examine an identified function

Thank you for your assistance,
Richard

Comment: The date and time are available via cgo, but C doesn't have macros for the other things you're describing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the -X linker flag to set the value of a string variable when building:

```
go build -ldflags "-X main.Uname '$(uname -a)' -X main.CompileTime '$(date)'"
```

With such command, this code

```
package main

import "fmt"

// Set by the linker.
var CompileTime, Uname string

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Uname)
    fmt.Println(CompileTime)
}
```

will print something like

```
Linux user 3.13.0-53 Wed May 20 10:34:39 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Wed May 27 12:00:00 UTC 2015
```

See the [linker docs](http://golang.org/cmd/ld/) for more info.

Comment: This will clearly work but I was hoping for something more built-in to isolate any changes from every developer and production build command line. Is injecting this information via the linker the only way?

Comment: @Richard This is the only way I know, apart from straight-up code generation. There isn't something like gcc's `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` macros in Go.